# Flexbox alignment - two on each row and then one

Tags: html, css, react-native, flexbox

I'll just add a pic of how I am trying to get the link boxes to align:

[examplepic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQZcz.png)

So two on each line, same size, and then one on the last left line. I have been experimenting with wrap, justifycontent and flex but I am not getting it right. Any tips? Code follows here;

```
return (

    <View style={styles.linkContainer}>

            <TouchableOpacity
                containerStyle={styles.linkContainerStyle}
                onPress={() =>
                    WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(
                        "https://skatt.skatteetaten.no/web/minskatteside/?innvalg=minearbeidsgivere#/minearbeidsgivere"
                    )
                }
            >
                <View style={styles.linkContainer}>
                    <Icon name="arrow-circle-right" size={15}></Icon>
                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold",fontSize: 13}}> Videregående opplæring </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>



            <TouchableOpacity
                containerStyle={styles.linkContainerStyle}
                onPress={() =>
                    WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(
                        "https://skatt.skatteetaten.no/web/minskatteside/?innvalg=minearbeidsgivere#/minearbeidsgivere"
                    )
                }
            >
                <View style={styles.linkContainer}>
                    <Icon name="arrow-circle-right" size={15}></Icon>
                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold",fontSize: 13}}> Lærling </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>




        <View style={styles.testTwo}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                containerStyle={styles.linkContainerStyle}
                onPress={() =>
                    WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(
                        "https://skatt.skatteetaten.no/web/minskatteside/?innvalg=minearbeidsgivere#/minearbeidsgivere"
                    )
                }
            >
                <View style={styles.linkContainer}>
                    <Icon name="arrow-circle-right" size={15}></Icon>
                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold",fontSize: 13}}> Høyere og anna utdanning </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>



            <TouchableOpacity
                containerStyle={styles.linkContainerStyle}
                onPress={() =>
                    WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(
                        "https://skatt.skatteetaten.no/web/minskatteside/?innvalg=minearbeidsgivere#/minearbeidsgivere"
                    )
                }
            >
                <View style={styles.linkContainer}>
                    <Icon name="arrow-circle-right" size={15}></Icon>
                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold",fontSize: 13}}> Grunnskoleopplæring </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>




            <TouchableOpacity
                containerStyle={styles.linkContainerStyle}
                onPress={() =>
                    WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(
                        "https://skatt.skatteetaten.no/web/minskatteside/?innvalg=minearbeidsgivere#/minearbeidsgivere"
                    )
                }
            >
                <View style={styles.linkContainer}>
                    <Icon name="arrow-circle-right" size={15}></Icon>
                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold",fontSize: 13}}> Sommerkurs </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>



);
```

}

and CCS:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({




linkContainer:{
    flexDirection: 'column',

},


linkContainerStyle:{
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "black",
    backgroundColor: "white",
},
```

});

I removed my attempts in CCS as its mostly a mess at this point. If anyone have any tips on how to get the icons to align on the same line as the text as well that would be great!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of the alignment you want

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 300px;
}

.container .item {
  width: 48%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    item1
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    item2
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    item3
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    item4
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    item5
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's nice … down to some screen width, then that `width: …` will become uncomfortable. :(

Comment: Yeah you should edit the width to your liking probably use percentages

Comment: this kind of worked but not 100%, Its in react native so can't use px. The first and second row left boxes have no space between them but the rest seems to work :))

Comment: Never worked with react so cant help you there sorry :) if you want to give the items some more space you could add margin-bottom to .item

Comment: Yeah I think it won't be to hard to figure out, now I have a very good starting point. Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: No problem, glad i could help! :)

Comment: @IngvildHagen: for nice gaps, you can use negative `margin-top/left` on the flex parent and the exact same values on the children flex items, but with positive values.